# Power level of stereo in Honda Element 7-speaker system

Tags: honda, audio, speakers, element

The [Honda Element](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Honda_Element) in United States offered a factory stereo and 7-speaker system with subwoofer, at least in the early years such as [2004](http://owners.honda.com/vehicles/information/2004/Element/). What is the power output from that stereo to the speakers?

I have read that factory-installed stereos often put out 15 [watts RMS per channel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Audio_power) or less, while after-market stereos often put out 16 watts RMS or more. I am would like to know into which camp the stereo falls as shipped by Honda for the 7-speaker system.

In choosing replacement speakers, you might want speakers with high sensitivity ratings (over 90 dB) for the lower-powered stereos, versus speakers with lower sensitivity ratings for the higher-powered stereos.

This [Honda specifications page for the 4-Speed Automatic 4WD EX](http://owners.honda.com/vehicles/information/2004/Element/specs#mid%5EYH2854PLW) says “270-Watt AM/FM/CD Audio System with 7 Speakers including Subwoofer”. How does that breakout to power delivered to the speakers in the front doors and rear doors?

Answer (score 0):

The head unit (or radio) is most commonly a 4 channel unit...the subwoofer will be channeled thru an external amp...if you were to change your head unit you would have to get a 6 channel unit (the 7nth speaker is the subwoofer) and the power supplied to each speaker from the head unit is different. That's why it's important to hook it up correctly. The head unit will feed more power to your rear speaker and not so much to the tweeters

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Hi Chris - your post doesn't answer the question, which asks what the power level is.